# Grails Geb functional test, setupData() method, data being created and rolled back, but not rendered

Tags: grails, automated-tests, grails-orm, spock, geb

I've been following the documentation [here](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html), specifically section 15.2. My understanding from this documentation is that integration tests roll back automatically after every test provided the following imports and annotations

```
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.gorm.transactions.*
import spock.lang.*

@Integration
@Rollback
```

And also provided that the setupData() method is called from within the test method, as only operations from within the test are rolled back.
My test class looks like this

```
package com.something.DashboardTest

import com.something.User

import geb.spock.GebSpec
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.gorm.transactions.*
import grails.transaction.*

import com.something.pages.DashboardPage

@Integration
@Rollback
class DashboardSpec extends GebSpec {

    void setupData() {
        User testUser = new User(
                fName: "Finn",
                lName: "Murtons",
                email: "finn@gmail.com",

        )
        assert testUser.validate() == true
        testUser.save()
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }


    void "when the test is executed..."() {
        when:
        setupData()

        and:
        to DashboardPage

        then:
        at DashboardPage
        assert User.getUserByEmail("finn@gmail.com").fName == "Finn" 
        assert $("h1.greeting$userId", 0).text() == "Hello Finn Murtons"
    }
}
```

According to the documentation, if the setupData() method is called from within the test method. then it should be rolled back after the test. In this case, the user is being created, and I'm sure because the second last assert statement is passing, the test is only failing on the last line. But the rendering of the user data fails for some reason

When I change it from void setupData() to void setup(), the test passes, but of course the transactions aren't rolled back. This is what the error report looks like for the test when it fails using the void setupData() approach

```
$("h1.greeting").text() == "Up match test"
|         |        |     |
[]       400       null false
```

I'm using Grails 3.3.9
This is merely a simplified representation of the actual problem, I can't share the full code for professional reasons.

Comment: You are calling `testUser.validate()` but not checking the return value so it won't really matter if the thing is valid or not.  Then you call `testUser.save()` which will validate it again.  Separate from that, why should `User.findByEmail("finn@gmail.com")` return a `Number`?

Comment: FYI... In the `then:` block, instead of `assert User.getUserByEmail("finn@gmail.com").fName == "Finn"` you should just have `User.getUserByEmail("finn@gmail.com").fName == "Finn"`.  You should not use the `assert` keyword.  Same with the assertion after that one.

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the findUserByEmailm statement, it originally returned an id, but that was redundant. Basically I'm just checking that the User created still exists right before the assertion that the user's name is being rendered on the dashboard.

Comment: The issue is, that the User does seem to be created, but it's not being rendered. This is more of a Grails theory question, but is there a reason why I would be able to find the user using GORM mid test, but that the user data is not actually being retrieved and displayed in the test?